# wxPython and wxJoystick

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a joystick that I would like to interface to in wxPython. I can connect to it just fine and get readings from 6 different axes. The problem is that my joystick (a [Logitech F310 Gamepad](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/controllers/7360)) had 8 different axes, not 6.

My question is, how can I get the other two axes values from the joystick?
I ran it though a quick python script to get what wxPython had to say about the joystick:
All of these functions were found on the wxPython [wxJoystick doc page](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Joystick-class.html).

```
print joy.GetPosition().x
print joy.GetPosition().y
print joy.GetZPosition()
print joy.GetRudderPosition()
print joy.GetUPosition()
print joy.GetVPosition()
print joy.GetPOVPosition()
print joy.GetPOVCTSPosition()
print joy.HasPOV()
print joy.HadPOV4Dir()
print joy.HasPOVCTS()
```

This yields normal values on the first 6 lines (values which I expect to have) but give -1 on the POVPosition functions and a False on the last three.

I'm looking for a way to find the last two axes values, and these aforementioned functions don't seem to be able to do it...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have the same joypad, and on Ubuntu I'm able to see and test all the axes and buttons using [jstest](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/jstest-gtk/). According to that program, axis 6 and 7 are the D-Pad, 2 and 5 are the left and right triggers, 0 and 1 are the left thumbstick, 3 and 4 are the right thumbstick.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was needing a confirmation on where the other axes were on the input device, and I _thought_ that the D-Pad was the culprit... Still though, I cant read 'em.